# Obj -C method declaration Classes/Objects

Tags: objective-c, methods, declaration

We beginners get confused when a method declaration has two or more arguments and I think it is always explained using withVariable or "create" or "and" and we think it is part of the mandatory syntax and this is confusing.

eg:

```
-(void) createBudget:(double) aBudget withExchangeRate: (float) anExchangeRate;
```

The format is

```
-(void) someMethod:(someType) value1  secondValue: (anotherType) value2 thirdValue:
```

(anotherType) value3;

So if the following declaration is correct I finally understand it. Please confirm:

```
-(void) myMethod: (int) x aSecondValue: (float) y aThirdValue: (double) z;
```

and the names of these 3 methods are

- 1.createbudget:withExchangeRate:----//Method has two colons thus two arguments
- 2.someMethod:secondValue:thirdValue:----//Method has three colons thus three arguments
- 3.myMethod:aSecondValue:athirdValue:---//Method has three colons thus three arguments

Please confirm that "with" is not part of the mandatory syntax and that my third method declaration is acceptable.

Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

The actual method signatures would be:

```
createbudget:withExchangeRate:
someMethod:secondValue:thirdValue:
myMethod:aSecondValue:athirdValue:
```

(note the extra colon at the end of the rightmost argument)

"with", "and".. are in no way mandatory. You can use whatever wording you like, but I think it helps keep things clear.

Comment: Thanx I was just editing and adding in the last colon when you replied!

Comment: So expanding on this in the following old style declaring and initialising an NSNumber: NSNumber*eTransaction = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:100];  could read   NSNumber*eTransaction = [[NSNumber alloc] x:100]; In other words initWithInt is just any variable name and not an actual Obj-C command??

Comment: Not really.. initWithInt is the actual method name - You can chose whatever wording you like for your method. In this case initWithInt *is* the method (which takes one argument - hence the colon)

Comment: One more thing.. I guess you might be thinking in terms of method name and parameters as different things. When it comes to method signature they are not.. e.g. the whole method:arg1:arg2 is the method name.